# Array of function pointers ( including member functions) throwing template specialization error

Tags: c++, pointers, stdbind, mem-fun

So, I have a class called Delegate that can store an array of function pointers. This is the code:

```
template<typename Func>
class delegate
{
private:
public:
    typename std::vector<Func> mListOfFunctions;
    void Bind(Func f)
    {
        mListOfFunctions.push_back(f);
    }
    template<typename...TArgs>
    void Invoke(TArgs&&...arg)
    {
        for (auto f : mListOfFunctions)
        {
            f(std::forward<TArgs>(arg)...);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage in Player.cpp:

```
delegate<void(float)> testDelegate;
testDelegate.Bind(std::bind(&Player::MoveLeft,this));
```

This throws the error C2893 (Error  C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)')

But when I change the definition of Bind to the following:

```
template<typename F>    
void Bind(F f)
{

}
```

It works fine, but when I try to push the function object into the vector it throws the same error again.

Is there anyway to resolve this?

I need to cache the pointers passed in.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `std::bind` is not a function pointer (it is a function object of an unspecified type), but you're trying to make it into one. Since you're using `std::forward`, you must be using C++11, which means you can use `std::function`:

```
template<typename Func>
class delegate
{
private:
public:
    typename std::vector<std::function<Func>> mListOfFunctions;
    void Bind(std::function<Func> f)
    {
        mListOfFunctions.push_back(f);
    }
    template<typename...TArgs>
    void Invoke(TArgs&&...arg)
    {
        for (auto f : mListOfFunctions)
        {
            f(std::forward<TArgs>(arg)...);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I changed it to the following and it still throws an error :  void Bind(std::function<returnType(TArgs...)> f)
 {
  mListOfFunctions.push_back(f);
 }

Comment: Why are you doing that? Why are you not using the code as I posted it?

Comment: I did that too : template<typename Func>
class delegate
{
private:
public:
 typename std::vector<std::function<Func>> mListOfFunctions;
 void Bind(std::function<Func> f)
 {
  mListOfFunctions.push_back(f);
 }
 template<typename...TArgs>
 void Invoke(TArgs&&...arg)
 {
  for (auto f : mListOfFunctions)
  {
   f(std::forward<TArgs>(arg)...);
  }
 }
}; but when I call Bind it throws that error again

Comment: Compiles perfectly: https://ideone.com/pBJB3P  Provide more information. Edit your question and show 1. How you are calling `Bind` 2. The EXACT new error message.

Comment: In your case you are not using a member function. But when I try to add a member function using std::bind and pass it as a std::function it throws the same error ( C2893) that was in the question

Comment: When i use a lambda or a global/static function it works perfectly. I need it to be able to bind to even a member function

Comment: Does your function take arguments? Are you forgetting that when you `std::bind`, you need to use placeholders for the arguments?

Comment: Oh I am not sure what placeholders are, but I think that might be it. Thanks for your help